# Doctrine, how to make 1 migration out of two you just made locally?

Tags: doctrine, migration, doctrine-migrations

So I'm messing around locally and made two migrations with the second having really very minor changes on top of the first one. We agreed as a team, when working on an issue, to keep migrations minimal. So I would like to make one out of these two, before making a comitting my code. My question is, how would I do that? Do I remove them and use `make:migration` again and it will generate the correct last updated version in one file instead of two or will I have to do something else?

Comment: You'll have to `execute --down` them first or it won't find any changes.

Comment: Wouldn't removing them have the same effect @msg? Like in PHPStorm and in the database migrations table.

Comment: Can't say for sure, I'm not familiar with PHPStorm, but I'd think not. Does it remove the version from `migration_versions` *and* the fields included in that migration automatically?

Comment: if you remove it from both PHPStorm and the database, then yes, the same thing is achieved. If I achieve that, do I just use make:migration again?

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me:

1- Make a backup of your database (if you have something important that you want to keep that is not in the fixtures, if you have any).

2- Remove both files from PHPStorm and their versions from the `migration_versions` table.

3- Do `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`, which will load the migrations up to the point before making any changes.

4- Carry out `php bin/console make:migration` to make a migration of the changes you made into 1 file.

5- Carry out `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` again to apply the changes you made.

This works with more than 2 files as well but may not fit every situation, so consider that first.